# Unable to start session from Appium CLI and Appium Desktop

Tags: appium, ios13, appium-ios, xcode11, appium-desktop

**Environment**

- Xcode Version : 11.0 (11A420a)
- Appium desktop version : 1.13.0
- Appium CLI version : 1.16.0-beta.1
- Desktop OS/Version used to run Appium : Mac OS 10.14.6
- Node.js version (unless using Appium.dmg) : 12.10.0
- Mobile platform/version under test : iOS 13.0
- Simulator : iPhone 8
- Appium Server : Appium CLI and Appium.dmg

**Scenario - 1**

- Launch appium server from terminal
- Open Appium Desktop
- Select New Session Window in menu
- Tab to Custom Server
- Remote host: localhost, Remote port: 4723, Remote path: /wd/hub
- Added my capabilities
- Start session

Issue: The error message show - The URL '/wb/hub/session' did not map to a valid resource [Issue_Of_Scenario1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXNFM.png)

Log of appium server running on terminal in scenario - 1:

> [debug] [GENERIC] Calling AppiumDriver.getSessions() with args: []
>   [debug] [GENERIC] Responding to client with driver.getSessions()
>   result: [] [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 3 ms - 40 [HTTP] [HTTP]
>   --> POST /wb/hub/session [HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"path-to-app","bundledId":"com.xyz","deviceName":"iPhone
>   8","deviceUDID":"C70FBC5C-1234-48E9-1234-9C24EF043E9F","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"13.0","simpleIsVisibleCheck":"true","useJSONSource":"true","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
>   [debug] [HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
>   [HTTP] <-- POST /wb/hub/session 404 1 ms - 57 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> DELETE
>   /wb/hub/session [HTTP] {} [debug] [HTTP] No route found. Setting
>   content type to 'text/plain' [HTTP] <-- DELETE /wb/hub/session 404 1
>   ms - 57 [HTTP]

**Scenario - 2**

- Open Appium Desktop
- Entered Host - 0.0.0.0 and Port - 4724
- Start Appium Server 1.13
- Click on Appium Inspector icon (Search icon)
- Tab to Custom Server
- Remote host: 0.0.0.0, Remote port: 4724, Remote path: /wd/hub
- Added my capabilities
- Start session

Issue: Screen display infinite loading spinner.
[Issue_Of_Scenario2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3lbl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is what you have as your url "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"?
If yes, remove the "/wd/hub/".
what you have should be this "http://127.0.0.1:4723".